# PHP HTTP headers values as array

Tags: php, arrays

I know the `getallheaders()` function gives me an array of http headers. But it gives a key - value such as

```
[Authorization] => oauth_consumer_key="publica5d53e674542272aefc2ea8ebf99bf9d771ed2b089bdfd1fbb74b5de69", oauth_signature="c7f63e8c01131d4384cdfe2cee5db7ce160aa27b", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1418220427", oauth_nonce="5488538b485ed", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Is there a way other than exploding the data manually, to turn the value above in to an associative array without the quote marks?

UPDATE

Just to be clear, the above is a key value of a PHP array, where `[Authorization]` is the key and `oauth_consumer_key="publica5d53e674542272aefc2ea8ebf99bf9d771ed2b089bdfd1fbb74b5de69", oauth_signature="c7f63e8c01131d4384cdfe2cee5db7ce160aa27b", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1418220427", oauth_nonce="5488538b485ed", oauth_version=“1.0”` is the value I’m trying to deconstruct.

Comment: no, there isn't. you got exactly what's in the headers. it's not Apache's (or PHP's) job to understand what every possible http header could be and parse it for you. it found Authorization, it gave you the value in the Authorization header. it's up to you to tear it apart into something more useful.

Comment: Ok, I couldn’t see anything in the PHP docs, but it was worth a shot if anyone knew a simpler built-in way. e.g. a variation on `parse_str()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple regex:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]+)", /', $header.', ', $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo($match[1].' -> '.$match[2]."\n");
}
```

I appended `", "` (comma and a space) to the header to simplify the regex.

Or you can try to parse the string manually:

```
foreach (explode(', ', $header) as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $item);
    $value = trim($value, '"');
    echo($key.' -> '.$value."\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that does exactly what you need in a single line of code:

```
$pieces = parse_ini_string(str_replace(', ', "\n", $header));
print_r($pieces);
```

Comment: It will fail if one of the values contains ", ". This can be fixed by adding the quote before comma into the expression that is replaced: `str_replace('", ', "\"\n", $header);`